# Setting a list of several values to one SSRS parameter in "Available values"

Tags: reporting-services

I have an (integer) multi-value parameter in my SSRS report. The "Available Values" for this parameter are currently gotten from a query returning an integer from 1 to 15. Everything is working fine when selecting one or several values.
Now, I would like to set by myself these a
Available Values (and not anymore via a query)  and group the several possible values in 3 groups : 1,2,3,4,5 and 6,7,8,9,10, and 11,12,13,14,15. What should be the syntax in the Value field (in the "Available Values")
[Report Parameters Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRfDI.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do this in the way you want. If you edit your question and explain how the parameter is used (is it used in a tablix filer, dataset file or passed the a dataset query?) then that would steer the answer. My gut would be to add an internal/report specific dataset that handles the mapping of the group to the actual values and then have another hidden parameter that contains the results that can be passed to your query as normal. If you need more help, update you question and add the relevant info.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your answer. This parameter is just passed to the query in the WHERE clause (  WHERE fieldame IN (@myparam)  ). I will certainly try the smart way you've suggested to solve this. I guess I'll have also to deal with a multi-value issue (when user chooses more than one group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create a permanent table to support this, handy if you need to use it from other projects. You could just add this as a report specific dataset but that seems like more work than it's worth.

```
CREATE TABLE RangeNumbers(RangeID int, Range varchar(20), iValue int)
INSERT INTO RangeNumbers VALUES 
(1, 'From 1 to 5', 1),
(1, 'From 1 to 5', 2),
(1, 'From 1 to 5', 3),
(1, 'From 1 to 5', 4),
(1, 'From 1 to 5', 5),
(2, 'From 6 to 10', 6),
(2, 'From 6 to 10', 7),
(2, 'From 6 to 10', 8),
(2, 'From 6 to 10', 9),
(2, 'From 6 to 10', 10),
(3, 'From 11 to 15', 11),
(3, 'From 11 to 15', 12),
(3, 'From 11 to 15', 13),
(3, 'From 11 to 15', 14),
(3, 'From 11 to 15', 15)
```

Of course you could normalise this more but I left it like this for the sake of simplicity.

Once you have this, you can create a dataset for your parameter values like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT RangeID, Range FROM RangeNumbers ORDER BY RangeID
```

I've ordered this so they appear in your report in a logical order
Let's assume this parameter is called `@ranges` and set the Value to `RangeID` and the Label to `Range`

Next create a hidden parameter, lets call this `@selectedNumbers`

Now create a new dataset using something like

```
SELECT iValue FROM RangeNumbers WHERE RangeID IN(@ranges)
```

This will then get populated with all the `iValue`s from the range table matching the selection the users made.

Finally in your main dataset you can just do

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE fieldName IN(@selectedNumbers)
```

That should be it.