# SSRS Specify Values using label, values

Tags: sql, vb.net, reporting-services, expression

I have a query that uses a where in (@). Customer is asking to have a single label with multiple values inside it.

| label | Value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1,2,3 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1,2 |

SSRS image example

[image: SSRS image example]

How can I add the values to the value field and have the @ query 1,2,3 for label a?

Comment: Storing data as comma separated values will only cause lots of problems...

Comment: This will depend a lot on how your data is stored and retrieved.  Could you maybe update your questions with details of the "@ query" at least and explain which fields will be concatenated for display

Comment: See an answer I posted to a very similar question a week ago ( not a colleague or yours is it?!)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181695/setting-a-list-of-several-values-to-one-ssrs-parameter-in-available-values/72230999#72230999